# Capturing and modifying redirects in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox extension that downloads a webpage.

Firefox is opened by another process (a web service) on the webpage specified at the command line (e.g. ./firefox http://www.example.com/). In the extension I have to download the website and notify a web service that I have completed the download and where to find the website downloaded.

I have the following problem : The web service that starts the Firefox process has to pass me a session identifier that it sends via a GET parameter in the website address (e.g. ./firefox http://www.example.com/?param=value). I have to send the value later with the completed response.

When the URL Firefox receives resolves to a webpage I have no problem downloading it and extracting the session id GET parameter and sending it back to the web service.

However, whenever I encounter a webpage that redirects, I lose the GET parameter. I have tried getting it from the Document.referrer attribute but sometimes that attribute is not filled even though a redirect has been performed.

I cannot change the current workflow of the application, I can only work on the extension. I have also tried monitoring "http-on-examine-response" and sometimes I can find 302 responses, sometimes I won't get them but some sort of redirection occurs.

I do not know a whole lot about these things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason why you prefer URL-based hacks as opposed to a custom command line parameter that your extension can read out? Concerning your question: you probably want to monitor `http-on-examine-cached-response` as well.

Comment: No reason at all. I just have to associate the input URL with the supplied identifier. If you can suggest a link or an answer to this, I'd be very grateful. I've also just found out that Firefox caches redirects. Thanks for that. Do redirects that are not cached set the Document.referrer attribute?

Comment: HTTP level redirects generally don't change `document.referrer`, it's set to the URL of the page where the link was placed. For a URL that isn't coming from a link it's actually surprising that you have a referrer at all - I guess that's JavaScript-based redirects then.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Any suggestion on the command line arguments and how I might get them? The Firefox process almost constantly running so other calls from the command line spawns new tabs. The tabs are closed after a while when they no longer have any activity.